# Parse the multiple attributes of stringified XML

Tags: java, xml

Below is the XML.I want parse and get id.But want those Ids which have INT values.Like in below XML there are four tags of Ids.I want those which not have valus as n/a.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?<xs:nml
xmlns:xs=\"http://www.netgear.com/protocol/transaction/NMLSchema-0.9\" src=\"nas\" dst=\"dpv_1349084626000\" locale=\"en-us\">
<xs:transaction ref_id=\"njl_id_991\" status=\"success\">
    <xs:response ref_id=\"njl_id_991\" status=\"success\">
        <xs:result
            xmlns:ns3=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ns3:type=\"xs:exResult\">
            <xs:get-s resource-type=\"Devices\">
                <Device_Collection>
                    <Device>
                        <alias>nas-1C-CA-AE</alias>                        
                        <id>3374</id>
                        <license>
                            <ExpiredTime>n/a</ExpiredTime>
                        <id>n/a</id>                             
                        </license>
                        <model>qwerty</model>
                        <online>true</online>
                    </Device>
        <Device>
                        <alias>nas-1C-CA-AE</alias>                        
                        <id>3375</id>
                        <license>
                            <ExpiredTime>n/a</ExpiredTime>
                        <id>n/a</id>                             
                        </license>
                        <model>qwerty1</model>
                        <online>true</online>
                    </Device>                       
                </Devices>
            </xs:get-s>
        </xs:result>
    </xs:response>
</xs:transaction>
```

I am parsing the xml this way and set the values in device response(which is bean class)

```
private boolean flagId = false;
private int count = 0;  

private final DeviceResponse deviceResponse = new DeviceResponse();

@Override
public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName, final Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {


    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        flagId = true;
        count++;
    }


}

@Override
public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName) throws SAXException {

}

@Override
public void characters(final char ch[], final int start, final int length) throws SAXException {

    if (flagId && count == 1) {
        final String id = new String(ch, start, length);
        flagId = false;
        deviceResponse.setId(id);
    }


}

/**
 * @return the deviceResponse
 */
public DeviceResponse getDeviceResponse() {
    return deviceResponse;
}
```

}

Comment: So what did you try? What is the problem that stops you from doing what you want?

Comment: actually I used SAX parser and only getting first id.Not other ones

Comment: Please add the code of your best attempt and we can go from there.

Comment: I have updated.Please go through once